# Any alternative for subreports in Crystal Reports

Tags: .net, winforms, crystal-reports

I have a 1-to-many relationship in my report. I used sub-reports to handle this situation but the reports became so slow that they were unusable. I want to know if there is any alternative to sub-reports in Crystal Reports that can be used to handle a 1-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it with the help of grouping. Below are the steps that I followed lets consider the example of single user having multiple communication details.

1. Created the stored procedure to return all the records(by joining user and communication table).
2. Performed group by on the main record (User-id)
3. Inside that group created the group by on communication-id.

   ***It improved the performance as compared to the sub-report.***

Comment: This is fairly basic CR functionality.  Please consider reading a book on the topic.

Comment: When you are stuck with the deadline you don't have time to read books.